# Android Jetpack Navigation start activity and navigate back functionality

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-navigation

Suppose we have 2 activity,
Activity A is a simple activity,
Activity B makes use of jetpack navigation.
Activity B's has 3 fragments in it, with the graph like:
(start destination) Fragment X -> Fragment Y -> Fragment Z
If I'm inside Activity A, how do I start activity B and simultaneously jump to Fragment Y
Also, when that is done, now I'm inside fragment Y, now when I navigate back, it should finish activity B, instead of taking me to Fragment X. What changes should I make to my navigation graph to achieve this?

Comment: Currently, for jumping into a fragment, I'm using NavDeepLinkBuilder. It provides pending intent on which I call send() function. It does the job but the calling activity finishes itself.

Comment: It sounds like you should just have Fragment Y within Activity A. Why is Activity B involved at all?